# fill fields in entity forms when checkbox is set

Tags: 7, entities

I have a entity form with some text fields. 
When the user checks a checkbox the fields should be filled with his user data (name,...) from his profile.

I tried to solve this with the conditional fields module. It works partially, in that I bind a new created state and end up in Javascript. Here I can set the value of the text field, but this new value never shows up in the form.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Please share setting for the conditional fields also.